# stripe get promotion codes in node.js

Tags: node.js, promotion-code, stripe-payments

I want to get promotion codes with stripe node.js API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/promotion_codes/list

```
    const stripe = require('stripe')('...');
    const promotionCodes = await stripe.promotionCodes.list({
      limit: 3,
    });
```

Throws an error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`

Other API endpoints work correctly.

Does stripe has any additional conditions to work with promotion codes?
I found only this info, but it doesn't answer my question: https://support.stripe.com/questions/promotion-codes

Comment: Make sure you're using at least https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/releases?after=v8.88.0 where support for that endpoint was added.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I updated and it works correctly. Thank you, you saved my day!